# Azure Fucntions 2.x and 3.x will no longer be supported? (Java)

Tags: java, azure-functions

The following article states that Azure Fucntions 2.x and 3.x will no longer be supported.

https://demiliani.com/2022/06/14/do-you-have-azure-functions-in-production-update-your-azure-functions-apps-to-use-runtime-version-4-x/

We are using Java, not .NET Core 3.1.

We would like to know if we need to update to version 4.x even if we are using Java.

Is our understanding correct that Java will continue to support the new features, security patches, and performance optimizations of versions 2.x and 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you are right but it depends upon the version of the language. According to this [Azure Functions - MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cazure-cli%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-java), the 2.x is still under support. The following table helps you to understand currently which version of java is supported in each runtime version.

> | JAVA Version | Run time Version |
> | --- | --- |
> | N/A | 1.x |
> | Java 8 | 2.x |
> | Java 11 & 8 | 3.x |
> | Java 11 & 8 | 4.x |

However, it is always recommended to use the latest version for your apps.

> Downgrades to v2.x aren't supported. When possible, you should always run your apps on the latest supported version of the Functions runtime.

**REFERENCES:** [Java developer reference for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption)